# PIP fails to install auto-py-to-exe

Tags: python, windows, pip, python-3.8

I have problem with PIP 3.8

```
C:\Users\iivoo\PycharmProjects\TEST\venv\Scripts>pip install auto-py-to-exe
Collecting auto-py-to-exe...

distutils.errors.DistutilsError: Setup script exited with error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\BIN\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\iivoo\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-gf4x4k83\gevent\
```

I don't know what is problem i have: latest visual studio c++ building tools, python 3.8, pip 3.8, latest pyinstaller, windows 10

Pls help me thank you!

Edit: Sorry bad english!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will try to give you a short list of reasons for this failure.

1. Auto Py To Exe uses (is based on) PyInstaller
2. PyInstaller has no support for Python 3.8
3. So, Auto Py To Exe doesn't work with Python 3.8.x but it does for Python : Python >= 2.7 ( including 3.7  ) [Read here](https://pypi.org/project/auto-py-to-exe/)

Comment: Btw. There is not such a PIP version 3.8. Next time, you should add the output of PIP LIST command.
It looks like this:

Package        Version
-------------- ----------
altgraph       0.16.1
Click          7.0
future         0.18.2
pefile         2019.4.18
pip            19.3.1
PyInstaller    3.5
PyQt5          5.14.0
PyQt5-sip      12.7.0
pyqt5-tools    5.13.0.1.5
python-dotenv  0.10.3
pywin32-ctypes 0.2.0
setuptools     41.2.0

Answer (score 0):

PyInstaller is not supported on Python 3.8 yet. This solution works:

```sh
    pip uninstall pyinstaller
    pip install https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/archive/develop.zip
    pip install -U gevent==1.5a3
    pip install -U auto-py-to-exe
```